# different auth tokens for google account

Tags: android, android-c2dm, google-authentication

I got a php code using cURL to get Google auth token for Gmail account. I am using it for `C2DM`. Everytime I run that script, I receive a different auth token. I thought every google account has an auth token which only gets refreshed sometimes. But as I said, I am getting different tokens every time. How should I manage so frequently changing token ? Whats the better way of using tokens ?

This is the code I used for getting AUTH TOKEN for my gmail account.

```
<?php
$ch_cl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch_cl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin");
curl_setopt($ch_cl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$data_cl = array('accountType' => 'GOOGLE',
    'Email' => 'xxxxxx@gmail.com',
    'Passwd' => 'xxxxxxxx',
    'source'=>'xxx-xxx-0.1',
    'service'=>'ac2dm'
);

curl_setopt($ch_cl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch_cl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch_cl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch_cl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_cl);

$cLresponse = curl_exec($ch_cl);
// echo $cLresponse;
curl_close($ch_cl);
//parse the $cLresponse and pick out the clientLogin 'Auth' token
$cLrespArrys = explode("\n", $cLresponse);
$authStr = explode("=", $cLrespArrys[2]);

// echo "return is:<br>" . $authStr[0] . "=" . $authStr[1];

$auth = $authStr[1];

echo "<br><br>" . $auth;
?>
```

here $auth contains the AUTH TOKEN issued.

Answer (score 0):

For C2DM the auth token is generated everytime you register with the C2DM service. Once you get the auth token after registering a particular device to the C2DM service, you can use the same auth token to communicate to the registered device as long as C2DM server doesn't refresh it. Check the [C2DM site](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/). The PHP code which you have might be probably calling the C2DM register service each time. Hope this helped.

Comment: I think u misunderstood. I m speaking abt the AUTH TOKEN that i need to pass to C2DM server while sending a message to the client devices. As i know AUTH TOKEN is issued for the GMAIL account we use for registering with C2DM servers. U r speaking abt the registration id that D2DM servers issues to every client application. I have updated my question. Plz have a look :) Thanks for the response.

Comment: @Kishan It's not difficult to type full words.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I am speaking about the AUTHORIZATION TOKEN that i need to pass to C2DM server while sending a message to the client devices. As i know AUTH TOKEN is issued for the GMAIL account we use for registering with C2DM servers. You are speaking about the registration id that D2DM servers issues to every client application. I have updated my question. Please have a look :) Thanks for the response (i am sorry i could not update the previous comment)